# ayuda con error con Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

Estoy haciendo un programa en consola mas que nada por diversión y me da el siguiente error:

> Property access must assign to the property or use its value.

Aquí es donde me da el error :

> personaje.arma(5)

El código de la clase es:

```
Class persona

    Private vida, daño As Integer
    Private nombre As String

    Public Property arma As Integer
        Get
            Return daño
        End Get
        Set(ByVal puño As Integer)
            daño = puño
        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property barra As Integer
        Get
            Return vida
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub aumento(ByVal subida As Integer)
        vida = vida + subida
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloca tu clase `persona` como publica:

```
Public class persona

...

End Class
```

y define correctamente el valor a la propiedad, este es el error:

```
personaje.arma(5)
```

debe ser:

```
personaje.arma = 5
```

Comment: dim personaje as persona = new persona()

Comment: y como construiste a 'personaje'?

Comment: Sub Main()
        Dim personaje As persona = New persona()

        System.Console.WriteLine(personaje.barra)
        personaje.aumento(5)
        System.Console.WriteLine(personaje.barra)
        System.Console.WriteLine(personaje.arma)
        personaje.arma(5)
        System.Console.WriteLine(personaje.arma)
        System.Console.ReadKey()

    End Sub

Comment: ok, cambia esto ´´personaje.arma(5)´ por ´personaje.arma = 5´

Comment: ahora si, muchas gracias